# How to get TItles of multiple People Or Group column's in list using REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013

I am new in sharepoint. I am using Sharepoint 2013.
I want to retrieve name and email id in People Or Group column using REST API.
My list contains two such columns. Please help me to retrieve title and email ids of both the columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to retrieve user field value using SharePoint REST

Using `$expand` OData operator you can specify that the request returns projected fields from `User Information List` list for user field.

**ListItem resource endpoint**: `https://[site]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)?$select=<user field name>/Name,<user field name>/EMail&$expand=<user field name>`

**Examples**

Assume a `Tasks` List that contains `AssignedTo` (*multi-valued*) and `Author` (*single-valued*) user fields.

The first example demonstrates how to retrieve `AssignedTo` column user details:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items(1)?$select=AssignedTo/Name,AssignedTo/EMail&$expand=AssignedTo
```

returns `Name` and `Title` for `AssigntedTo` column:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "764f494a-7186-4b83-9db0-2bcf1a0930a5",
            "uri": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'71284427-d86e-424f-ae07-2e0c53b9ac4a')/Items(1)",
            "etag": "\"3\"",
            "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
        },
        "AssignedTo": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "id": "a06b28ff-9356-4aa9-8f38-f75107058fd2",
                        "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
                    },
                    "Name": "i:0#.f|membership|username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "EMail": "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve `Author` and `AssignedTo` user field user values:

Endpoint Url: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items(1)?$select=Author/Name,Author/EMail,AssignedTo/Name,AssignedTo/EMail&$expand=AssignedTo,Author`

Result:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "e29690e4-3813-44ce-a828-160ad072666d",
            "uri": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'71284427-d86e-424f-ae07-2e0c53b9ac4a')/Items(1)",
            "etag": "\"3\"",
            "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
        },
        "Author": {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "6dc8fe57-1865-464f-aaa3-f7b8bb555f20",
                "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
            },
            "Name": "i:0#.f|membership|username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            "EMail": "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        "AssignedTo": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "id": "b9a1d6f8-4bec-4ec8-b940-fdaeac2eff37",
                        "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
                    },
                    "Name": "i:0#.f|membership|username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "EMail": "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**JavaScript example**

```
function getItemDetails(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,selectFields, expandFields){
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId + ")";
    endpointUrl+= '?$select=' + selectFields.join(",");
    endpointUrl+= '&$expand=' + expandFields.join(",");
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'GET');
}


function executeRequest(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    if (typeof headers == 'undefined'){
        headers = {};
    }
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}



var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var selectFields = ['Author/Name','Author/EMail','AssignedTo/Name','AssignedTo/EMail'];
var expandFields = ['Author','AssignedTo'];
getItemDetails(webUrl,'Tasks',2,selectFields,expandFields)
    .done(function(data){
         //print MULTI-valued user field: AssignedTo
         console.log('AssignedTo user field value:')
         for(var i = 0; i< data.d.AssignedTo.results.length;i++) {
             console.log(data.d.AssignedTo.results[i].EMail); 
             console.log(data.d.AssignedTo.results[i].Name);       
         }

         //print SINGLE-valued user field: Author 
         console.log('Author user field value:')
         console.log(data.d.Author.EMail);
         console.log(data.d.Author.Name);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim Gremyachev It really worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: I want to retrieve the OOTB ModifiedBy value using the RESt Query. I tried using : Editor/Title&$expand=Editor and also tried Editor/Name&$expand=Editor. But, no luck. Could you please suggest?

Comment: What will happened if AssignedTo field allows multiple selection? How should I get those values